# how to refresh jquery Datatable after an operation?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable, the first column show agencies assigned to this row, in another column I have a button that when clicked show a form to assign new agencies to this row, everything work well, but for the new agencies added I have to refresh the page to see them, is there any way to add them as soon as I click the button "Assign" ?

here is an image showing what I am talking about :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You should refresh your datatable data when assign new agency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
if (success)
{
    var theDiv = $("<li/>");
    theDiv.html("<input type='checkBox' value='"+newItemValue+"'/> " + newItemName);
    theDiv.appendTo($("#theParentElement"));
}
```

You create a new DOM element when all goes as expected and then you pass it into your main holder.

Answer (score 0):

```
function initDataTable() {
   var oOverviewTable =$('#myTable').dataTable(
      {
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bJQueryUI": true,  
      "bLengthChange": false
      "sAjaxSource": '/Helpdesk/ActiveCases/noacceptancetest'
    });
 }

  function RefreshTable(tableId, urlData)
  {
     $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
      {
         table = $(tableId).dataTable();
         oSettings = table.fnSettings();

         table.fnClearTable(this);

     table.fnDraw();
   });
 }

 function reloadTable()
 {
   RefreshTable('#HelpdeskOverview', '/Helpdesk/ActiveCases/noacceptancetest');
  }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     initDataTable();
  });

  //now call reloadTable function in agency assing event
```

the original post can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934144/how-to-reload-refresh-jquery-datatable)

Comment: none of these worked for me, I am not using a json data, I am iterating through a list of beans coming from a session.

Comment: In that case, transform yous list of beans into json data