# How to use datatables.js in Vue.js2 project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2

I want to create a reactive Datatable in my Laravel + Vue.js project. I'm using `datatables.js` library to show my data. When I make an API call to get the data from db API returns me an array, so I want to populate that array in the `datatable`. But it's working weird?

**Here's API call:**

```
methods: {
    getUsers() {
        axios.get('/api/users')
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200) {
                    this.users = response.data.users;
                    console.log(this.users);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
},
mounted() {                
    $('#users-datatable-responsive').DataTable();
    this.getUsers();
}
```

**This is how I populating the data in the `datatable`**

```
<tr v-for="user in users">
    <td>@{{ user.fullname }}</td>
    <td>@{{ user.phone }}</td>
    <td>@{{ user.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

**And here's the weird result:**
[image]

Searching and other features of a datatable aren't working. What's the workaround?

**Edited:**

```
mounted() {               
    let table = $('#users-datatable-responsive').DataTable({
        language: this.dataTableOptions
    });
    this.getUsers();
    table.rows().invalidate().draw();
}
```

This approach didn't work for me.

Comment: That's because DataTables plugin does not automatically detect changes in DOM and updates its internal mapping of your data. You should force the instance to refresh, by invalidating the data and redrawing it, i.e. `table.rows().invalidate().draw();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I refresh/reload my DataTable from HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529662/how-do-i-refresh-reload-my-datatable-from-html-source)

Comment: @Terry please look at my editings.

Comment: @Terry this approach didn't work for me

Comment: Probably because you are refreshing the table before axios actually successfully fetches the data and updates Vue's data store, since axios' operations are asynchronous.

Comment: @Terry `table.rows().invalidate().draw();` I put it to the `then()` method of `axios` but it's still not working. How should I properly do that?

Comment: See my answer: you probably need to rely on `Vue.nextTick()` also, to ensure that the DOM has been updated by VueJS before you attempt to reset the table.

Comment: Try using a watcher on 'users' to perform the invalidate and draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get Terry's answer to work, but after a little bit of playing around found that that destroying the table before render, then rebuilding the table on the next tick does work.

```
...
methods: {
        drawDT() {
          $("#dt").DataTable().draw();
        },
        async refreshData() {
          this.isLoading = true;
          $("#dt").DataTable().destroy();
          try {
            let data = await fetchData();
            this.users = data.slice(0, getRandomInt(1, data.length));
            await this.$nextTick(this.drawDT);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } finally {
            this.isLoading = false;
          }
        }
      },
...
```

[Full example here](https://codepen.io/garymcm/pen/wmXMGM?editors=0011)

Comment: It gets me the same effect as Terry's (((

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As you can see, my example is working, so hopefully it's of some help you. Otherwise can you post your code somewhere so others can hopefully spot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, there are two issues that are causing the problem you are seeing:

1. DataTable plugin does not automatically updates its internal cache when you update the DOM. You will need to use its API to 'reset' the table, i.e. `table.rows().invalidate().draw();`
2. Axios works asynchronously, and you should reset the table only when the promise has been resolved. This should ideally be done using a custom method to keep things abstract :)

- In your custom method, you must wait for VueJS to finish updating the DOM, since the DOM relies on iterating through `this.users` to render the correct markup. Use [`Vue.nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to call the logic that 'resets' the table.

To fix this, you can call a custom method in your app/component that handles forced refreshing of the table, i.e.:

```
methods: {
    getUsers() {
        axios.get('/api/users')
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200) {
                    // Populate VueJS data store with received data
                    this.users = response.data.users;

                    // Call a method that manually refreshes table
                    this.forceRefreshUserDataTable();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
},
mounted() {             
    this.usersDataTable = $('#users-datatable-responsive').DataTable();
    this.getUsers();
},
methods: {
    forceRefreshUserDataTable() {
        Vue.nextTick(function () {
            this.usersDataTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: $(...).rows is not a function". This's the result.

Comment: @КамиловТимур Whoops, my bad. You can either choose to store the instantiated DataTable object (i.e. `this.usersDataTable = ...`), or chain `.DataTable()` to access the API, i.e. `$('#users-datatable-responsive').DataTable().rows().invalidate().draw()`

Comment: Which type does `usersDataTable` has? Cz ur code doesn't still work ((

Comment: after the `nextTick()` `datatable` is being truncated, right? And now, how to repopulate the `users` array to the `datatable`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple table you could use this grid table component from vue docs
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html