# DataTable refresh button with local data not ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i'm using DataTables in a coldfusion project so i want to create a refresh button for my table  without using ajax but by using the sent data from my CFC.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.refresh = {
    text: 'Refresh'
  , action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
      dt.clear().draw();
      dt.ajax.reload();
}}
    

var table = $(divname).dataTable({
          data: data,
           columns: columns,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: ['refresh'],
         "oLanguage": language_datatable,
      });
      return table;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I refresh/reload my DataTable from HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529662/how-do-i-refresh-reload-my-datatable-from-html-source)

Comment: it helps but i want to use that code into my refresh button how can i possibly transfer it to the button please i want to use the code inside the datatable declaration not in html because i m using global function