# How can I update the value of a DataTables column on drawCallback (page changed) event?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a paged DataTable and I would like to update the content for a specific column for the current visible page after that the page is loaded.
I found out that the event that fires when the table page is loaded is drawCallback, so I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#dataTables-ordini').DataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "sType": 'numeric' },
                    { "sType": 'string' },
                    { "sType": 'date' },
                    { "sType": 'numeric' },
                    { "sType": 'string' },
                    { "sType": 'numeric' },
                    { "sType": 'string' } ],
            order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            responsive: true,
            drawCallback: function(settings) {
                
                $('.numero_ordini_prec:visible').each(function(index){
                    var id = $(this).attr('myid');
                    var cell = $(this);
                    var cell_dom = this;
                    
                    if (cell.html() == 'ND') {
                        $.get('get_data.php?id='+id, function(data){
                            cell.html(data);
                            table.cell( cell_dom ).draw();
                        });
                    }
                });
                
                
            }
    });
});
```

It works, but there is a problem with the refresh of the data just updated: if I invalidate like this `table.cell( cell_dom ).invalidate().draw();`
it goes in an infinite loop because on each invalidate it raise the drawCallback.
If I only run table.cell( cell_dom ).draw(); it works but it goes back to visualize the first page, also if I clicked the 2 or third page.

So the question is: how can I update a cell in a drawCallback without these problems?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the DataTables [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) API call. You will see that it allows you to provide a boolean or a string as its parameter. These can be used to control whether the pagination is reset or preserved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redraw the data table without losing the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617903)