# TypeError: $ (...).bootstrapTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

```
<table id="selectCaseTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <!-- table code... -->
</table>

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/static/adminlet-2.4.10/dist/js/demo.js"></script>

<srcipt>
fuctions addSelectCase(){
    ...
    $("#selectCaseTable").bootstrapTable('refresh');
}
</script>
```

When I call `bootstrapTable("refresh")` like below

```
$("#selectCaseTable").bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

I see error on console

> TypeError: $(...).bootstrapTable is not a function

Comment: You need to initialize `bootstrapTable` first before using refresh on the same. `$("#selectCaseTable").bootstrapTable();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to be calling `Datatable()` not `bootstrapTable()` as shows the code below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

For further knowledge click here to see previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934144/how-to-reload-refresh-jquery-datatable) .

Comment: DataTable and Bootstrap table are two different things
see: 
* https://bootstrap-table.com/ 
* https://datatables.net/

He can call `bootstrapTable()` if he loads the library properly, or as you said he can call `DataTable()` because that's the library he loaded

Answer (score 3):

> TypeError: $ (…).bootstrapTable is not a function

This error is given when the initial `$('#example').DataTable();` after the `bootstrapTable` library you must include

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

After the call `$('#example').DataTable();` function.

it's a common issue for any script or function not loaded but you call it then this error given by the client site browser.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

I just added bootstrap related files (js and css) after jquery related files and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('button[name="refresh"]').click()
```

only you need set in your table

```
data-show-refresh="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```js
let table = $('#table').bootstrapTable({});

table.bootstrapTable('getData')
```