# $('#table').bootstrapTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

After updating from bootstrap-table v. 1.14.2 to bootstrap-table v. 1.15.2 I got this error

`Uncaught TypeError: $('#table').bootstrapTable is not a function`

**Note:**

I found that the problem is that `bootstrapTable` function doesn't end up in jQuery elements prototype. I looked to the dist folder in node_modules/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js and saw this (for v 1.15.2):

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory(require('jquery')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['jquery'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, global.BootstrapTable = factory(global.jQuery));
}(this, function ($) {
    // do some stuff
    $.fn.bootstrapTable = function (option, ...args) { ... }
    // do some other stuff
 }));
```

while for version for v 1.14.2 it looked like this:

```
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) { define([], factory); }
  else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") { factory(); }
  else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory();
    global.bootstrapTable = mod.exports;
  }
})(this, function () {
    // do some stuff
    $.fn.bootstrapTable = function (option, ...args) { ... }
    // do some other stuff
});
```

The thing is that in version 1.15.2. we **require new instance of jQuery**, so when I use `$('#table').bootstrapTable`, `$` here is different form the same variable in `bootstrap-table.js`, but in 1.14.2 we **use global $ variable**, so when I use `$('#table').bootstrapTable`, `$` is the same object as in in `bootstrap-table.js`, so we have our `bootstrapTable` function. Can I somehow resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160322/typeerror-bootstraptable-is-not-a-function - This may help

Comment: Unfortunately no, this answer is not connected to bootstrap-table library