# Add library css in Ruby on Rails 6 with webpacker

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install a library, specifically bootstrap-table via yarn. I had tried the gem found at the following link [Click](https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails) but it is an old version and I was unable to get it to work. I have read around that however with Rails 6 it is better to use the webpacker to install libraries. My problem now is I can't figure out how to insert bootstrap-table css.

Here are my files:

application.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("jquery-ui")
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
require("leaflet");
require("easy-autocomplete")

require bootstrap-table
```

application.scss

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self



 */

@import "leaflet/dist/leaflet";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
@import 'easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete';
```

In app/views/layouts/application.htlm.erb I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Resto</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <!-- This refers to app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss-->
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>


  </head>

  <body>
    <p class = "notice" ><%= notice %> </p>
    <p class = "alert" ><%= alert %></p>
    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

I read on the internet that to insert the css of the libraries installed by yarn I have to paste the following code in application.html.erb file:

```
<% = stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
```

So what I did was put this code in the file and I edited `config/webpacker.yml` to be sure it has `extract_css: true` in the default section at the top.

I also started the `bin / webpack-dev-server` command in the console but I got this error:

```
You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment

unless you are using the webpack -w or the webpack-dev-server.

webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.

You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.

Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.

Your manifest contains:

{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-105ced549e0eccca7ef2.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-105ced549e0eccca7ef2.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-105ced549e0eccca7ef2.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-105ced549e0eccca7ef2.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like not to have to use all this configuration but to just add the bootstrap-table css file to my page. I don't feel like good in running this `bin / webpack-dev-server` command. This is because I had a lot of errors after running this command and I would like to avoid having to keep it running all the time. It's possible? If that's not possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install the Gem, use this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-table-rails', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.1'
```

More info on this here: https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-table-rails/versions/1.8.1

Then in your terminal, run this:

```
bundle install
```

That should install the Gem/Library.

Comment: I installed the gem and I added in application.js:


//= require bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table


In application.scss:


 *= require bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table


But It still doesn't work! I receive this error in the Firefox console: 


Uncaught TypeError: $table.bootstrapTable is not a function

Comment: Try calling Datatable() not bootstrapTable(). Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160322/typeerror-bootstraptable-is-not-a-function